# Conflict type QString and std::string in a parameter

Tags: c++, qt, structure

I think my problem is simple to solve, but due to my lack of knowledge, I can't find the answer.

I have this structure :

```
struct variableOutil {
    std::string Nom;   
    float Valeur;   
    std::string Module;    
    std::string Unite;    
    std::string Format;    
    std::string Accesibilite;    
    std::string Description ;
};
```

And the problem come from here :

```
struct variableOutil ToleranceTensionAvion;
ToleranceTensionAvion.Nom = "ToleranceTensionAvion";
QTableWidgetItem* newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
newItem->setText(ToleranceTensionAvion.Nom);
this->ui->variableTableWidget->setItem(1,0,newItem);
```

I've got this error :

```
No matching function for call to 'QTableWidgetItem::setText(std::string&)
```

The problem is that setText need a `const QString &text` and tell me that I put in parameter a `std::string&` , I don't understand why does the type don't match, and what's the difference, after all, this is a simple String.

Thank you.

Comment: why u expect to `QString` and `std::string` be matched?

Comment: Because in the end it's just this : " "
And how to put Qstring in my structure so ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814189/how-to-change-string-into-qstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert `std::string` to `QString` by :

```
newItem->setText(QString::fromStdString(ToleranceTensionAvion.Nom));
```

Or

```
newItem->setText(QString::fromUtf8(ToleranceTensionAvion.Nom.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
newItem->setText(QString::fromUtf8(ToleranceTensionAvion.Nom.c_str());
```

`QString` allows only Unicode.
`std::string` just stores the bytes and does not work with encodings. The best way to store your texts would probably be *UTF-8 encoding*.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different classes, and `std::string`can not be used in place of `QString`. You can build `QString` from`std::string` and pass it.

```
QString s =QString::fromStdString(ToleranceTensionAvion.Nom);
newItem->setText(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `c._str()` on your `std::string` and it will work for anything that expects a `QString`