# Converting std::string to QString in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, most-vexing-parse

I cannot understand why `std::string` converted into QString while passing it to constructor. Here is small example:

```
  class StringHandler
 {
 private:
     QString str;
 public:
     StringHandler(QString s): str(s) {}
  };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::string str = "string";
    QString qstr(str); // it gives error there are no constructor QString(std::string)
    StringHandler handler(QString(str));//it does not give an error. Why?

    return a.exec();
 }
```

**EDIT:**

```
class StringHandler
{
public:
    StringHandler(QString s): str(s) {}
    QString str;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

std::string str = "string";
StringHandler handler(QString(str));//Here should be error, but there no error. Why?
qDebug()<<handler.str; //Error is here: request for member 'str' in 'handler', which is of non-class type 'StringHandler(QString)'

return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: add the actual error output, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change string into QString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814189/how-to-change-string-into-qstring)

Comment: @zenith The problem is not about error. I don.t understand why this line:`StringHandler handler(QString(str))` works.

Comment: And does it compile if you remove the `QString qstr(str);` line and just leave the other one?

Comment: @J A. Yes. compiler gives no error and no warning. And program runs without termination, when I remove `QString qstr(str)`

Comment: **Really**, we need the compiler error that you get in the non-working state. **This normally should not work**.

Comment: your EDIT shows  a completely unrelated error. you should put this in a different question.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I have edited the question

Comment: I saw that, and you made it worse. see my comment above.

Comment: Still, **where is the compiler error for the first, non-edited version**? We've asked you to add that, and you refuse to, as it seems, so I'm voting to close this because *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. "*

Comment: @Marcus Müller. As I sad there no error if I remove `QString qstr(str)` line. I understand error associated with that line and I did not post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say hello to the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

`StringHandler handler(QString(str));` declares a function named `handler` that takes a `QString` and returns a `StringHandler`. Yes. Thanks to the C++ parsing rules.

Now the error message `request for member 'str' in 'handler', which is of non-class type 'StringHandler(QString)'` makes sense: `handler` is being treated like a function of type `StringHandler(QString)` and you're trying to access a member named `str` in it, but of course functions have no members so the compilation fails.

You can fix this by using the uniform initialization syntax:

```
StringHandler handler{QString(str)};
```

The above can't be parsed as a function declaration, and so the compilation should fail for the *expected* reason: no matching constructor `QString(std::string)`.

For more info, see [C++'s most vexing parse again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16588750/3425536).