# Why can´t I iterate over findChild<QWidget*>() in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some `QCheckBox` named from "cb0" to "cb11".
Why get I an error, trying this, or why if thats the reason would it accept no `std::strings`?

```
using namespace std

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
   ostringstream strs;
   strs << i;
   string k = "cb" + strs.str();

   QCheckBox *cb = findChild<QCheckBox*>(k);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I would just use a QString for that (making use of QString::arg()). Although it would help your question if you put whatever error you have in your question as text. I have no idea what error you have.

Comment: If you are getting a compiler error you should include it.

Comment: Replace `QCheckBox *cb = findChild<QCheckBox*>(k);` with `QCheckBox *cb = findChild<QCheckBox*>(QString("cb%1").arg(i));` Why are you doing `i+1` when your combo boxes are cb0 ... cb11?

Comment: thanks, i+1  is anly a kind of typo, cause thats not my actual code

Comment: If you want it to accept std::string you probably have to use `QCheckBox *cb = findChild<QCheckBox*>(QString::fromStdString(k));` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814189/how-to-change-string-into-qstring