# How to add a struct value to a QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, struct, qstring

I am trying to copy a value stored in a `vector` to an empty `QStringList` (as shown in the following code):

```
QStringList acceptedIPListFromFile()
{
..............

    // Read the file until the end
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        getline (inFile,line);

        string token;
        stringstream stream(line);          
        vector<string> vect;
        while(getline(stream, token, delim) )
        {
            vect.push_back(token);
        }
        d.Name = vect[0];
        d.IP = vect[1];
        d.Port = vect[2];
        AllData.push_back(d);
        accepted_ip_list.append(d.IP);
        count++;
        vect.clear();
    }
.....................
}
```

BUT I am receiving an error while compiling:

```
no matching function for call to 'QStringList::append(std::__cxx11::string&)'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change string into QString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814189/how-to-change-string-into-qstring)

Comment: Change to `accepted_ip_list.append(QString::fromStdString(d.IP));` or `accepted_ip_list << QString::fromStdString(d.IP);`

Comment: thank you; that solved the issue.